# Special Characters in sharepoint 2010 file/folder name?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, folder, file

What special characters are allowed and not allowed in sharepoint file/folder names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rules are "very simple" ([see the full KB article here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;905231#appliesto)), which is why you should alway use [SPUrlUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461295.aspx) to check filenames.

Except about folders and files:

> **Folder names**
>   •You cannot use the following characters anywhere in a folder name or a server name:
>   ◦tilde
>   ◦number sign
>   ◦percent
>   ◦ampersand
>   ◦asterisk
>   ◦braces
>   ◦backslash
>   ◦colon
>   ◦angle brackets
>   ◦question mark
>   ◦slash
>   ◦pipe
>   ◦quotation mark
>   •You cannot use the period character consecutively in the middle of a
>   folder name.
>   •You cannot use the period character at the end of a
>   folder name.
>   •You cannot start a folder name with the period
>   character.
>
> **File names**
>   •You cannot use the following characters anywhere in a file name:
>   ◦tilde
>   ◦number sign
>   ◦percent
>   ◦ampersand
>   ◦asterisk
>   ◦braces
>   ◦backslash
>   ◦colon
>   ◦angle brackets
>   ◦question mark
>   ◦slash
>   ◦pipe
>   ◦quotation mark
>   •You cannot use the period character consecutively in the middle of a file name.
>   •You cannot use the period character at the end of a file name.
>   •You cannot start a file name with the period character.
>   •In addition, file names and folder names may not end with:
>   ◦.files
>   ◦_files
>   ◦-Dateien
>   ◦_fichiers
>   ◦_bestanden
>   ◦_file
>   ◦_archivos
>   ◦-filer
>   ◦ _tiedostot
>   ◦_pliki
>   ◦_soubory
>   ◦_elemei
>   ◦_ficheiros
>   ◦_arquivos
>   ◦_dosyalar
>   ◦_datoteke
>   ◦_fitxers
>   ◦ _failid
>   ◦_fails
>   ◦_bylos
>   ◦_fajlovi
>   ◦ _fitxategiak

Comment: Can you escape any of these? Using a HEX code for example?

Answer (score 0):

You should call SPEncode.UrlEncode, passing in filename.